# Convert a date string of format: "2017-01-03 16:50:00.0" to NSDate

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am getting back a `nil` string when I use the following:

```
    NSString *formatString = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS.Z";
    NSString *dateString = @"2017-01-03 16:50:00.0";

    NSDateFormatter *newDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
   [newDateFormatter setDateFormat:formatString];
   [newDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
   [newDateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale]];

   NSDate *newDate = [newDateFormatter dateFromString: dateString];
```

When I log my output, I have a non-nil date `newDateFormatter` but a  `nil` `newDate`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Good luck with that :)

Comment: When you are stucked with DateFormat: Cut it until you find which part of your format is wrong. For instance  `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS` & `"2017-01-03 16:50:00` work (but it should be `ss`, if you replace `00` with `33`, you'll see it). So, it's the "Z" part. The doc for DateFormat in iOS is there: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns You'll see that you can't translate the late `0` as timeZone with `Z`. I don't know what it's supposed to represent, but you need to find it out. My guess: => `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS`

Answer (score 1):

When I removed the `.Z`from the formatter and the `.0` from the date it worked fine and the `newDate` value was `2017-01-03 16:50:00 UTC`

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, but given that I can't control the input it is not helpful to remove the `.01`. Also I am not convinced there isn't a solution to the format I am looking at.

Comment: Try with `2017-01-03 16:50:33`, it won't work correctly, giving 00 for seconds instead of 33.